# Using the Xwiki WYSIWYG editor in Grails .gsp files?

Tags: grails, groovy, wysiwyg, gsp, xwiki

I'm using Grails for one of my projects, and I've got the Xwiki rendering plugin (see http://grails.org/plugin/xwiki-rendering) installed. Now I wonder whether there is any way to use the [xWiki WYSIWYG editor](http://platform.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/Features/WysiwygEditor) inside my .gsp files?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Using the XWiki Wsywiyg editor should be possible. You can check some documentation [here](http://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/WYSIWYG+Editor+Module#HUsetheWYSIWYGeditoroutsideXWiki) and also check [this](http://lists.xwiki.org/pipermail/users/2012-September/023902.html) which is an example of an XWiki Platform branch allowing to build the XWiki Wysiwyg editor standalone.

You can come ask questions in the XWiki dev lists if you need help (See the xwiki.org web site)

Comment: Thanks alot for those links! Still, I have never used XWiki before so I have quite some problems comprehending that stuff.
As far as I get this, the example in the first link you postet includes only one external file (<script type="text/javascript" src="xwe/xwe.nocache.js"></script>), but how to get/build that file? I'd really appreciate some more help :)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue on one of my project. It's not easy because the editor is part of the XWiki platform so you'll have to download the source code and extract it (there is no standalone editor).

What I did instead is using [MarkItUp](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/) as it supports Wiki tags (and you can add custom macros).

Comment: Thanks, but if I get it right, MarkItUp is no WYSIWYG editor... and that's what I need!

Comment: You're rigth we are using Wiki tag (with live preview). I think you should be able to find a WYSIWYG for wikis and include it in your project.